# Sum of negative and positive integers leads to unexpected output - c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an 2D-array, willing to check whether the sum of (every) column is 0 or not. Further more, adding to integers from the array seems to lead to unexpected output.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
long long int lines;
int temp;
int is_0 = 1;
cin>>lines;
int numbers[3][lines];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < lines; j++){
        cin>>temp;
        numbers[i][j]=temp;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    temp = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<lines;j++){
        temp += numbers[i][j];          
    }
    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

example input:

```
2
1
1
1
-1
-1
-1
```

example output:

```
2
0
-2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code doesn't need `temp` in the input loop. `std::cin >> numbers[i][j];` works just fine.

Comment: Draw a picture; what values go where when the code reads the input? What values go where when in the loops that calculate the sums? Hint: the name `lines` is misleading.

Comment: `cin>>lines; int numbers[3][lines];`  looks like a VLA.  I thought VLA was not standard in C++.  Perhaps this case a compiler extension is used?

Answer (score 2):

The program works as expected.
You are creating the following matrix

```
 1   1
 1  -1
-1  -1
```

and here

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    temp = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<lines;j++){
        temp += numbers[i][j];          
    }
    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
```

You are summing up the numbers of each row.

Comment: Cool! +1 This shows the difference between verification and validation . . .